# How to refer to an object and a string with the same name in an R function?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have this function (which doesn't seem to work):

```
cluster_per_project <- function(clusterX_PR_ids, name){
  clusterX_PR_ids_new <- clusterX_PR_ids           %>% 
                           select(project, PR_ids) %>%
                           filter(project == name)
  project_cX <- name[rownames(name) %in% clusterX_PR_ids_new$PR_ids,]
  output <- seqdef(project_cX, right = "DEL")
  return(output)
}
```

I think the problem is that the input `name` should should be a string (i.e. "name") on row 1 of the function, but an object (i.e. name) on row 3. Is there a way to adjust for this behavior, or do I simply need to pass two parameters (`name` and `"name"`)?

Comment: I assume that outside the function you have a data.frame for each of the different projects? The goal of the function remains unclear...

Comment: The question only concerns have to treat an input to a function as `name` and `"name"` alternatively in the simplest way possible.

Comment: Try `?eval`, it should do what you wish if you pass a string.